# C# get Twitter screen_name or user_id from Email

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, twitterizer

Hello I am making a website where users login ( with our own ID, they cant login with google, facebook or twitter) and I want to fetch their Twitter profile picture from their email adress, which was provided to us when they registered (basically check if an screen_name/userID with the provided email adress exists on Twitter).

I know how to get the user information with a static screen_name (for example my own). The problem is that i cant get their info from their email adress even though its used for loging in on Twitter (or better said i dont know how).

Simplified:

User logs in > we check their email > **fetch twitter userID from email** > get their profile picture

The bolded out part is the one i dont know how to do.

Same question for facebook :D

Comment: What parts of the Twitter API have you looked at?  Is there something in those documents that you need help with?

Comment: Most of their APIs require screen_name or user_id, but the only thing that i have is the users email adress. So i want to know how to get the user_id from email.

If its possible

Comment: Yes you will need to use some sort of API for that application, more than likely using the twitter API you will need to create "get_requests" etc using the API as well.  Or maybe use a  simple REST API

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/search/node/email%20language%3Aen), you will not be able to look a user up by email address.  You would be far better off requesting their Twitter handle.

If you think about it this makes perfect sense.  It protects a somewhat private piece of information.

Comment: So basicaly there is no way for me to find their user_id from the email provided.

Comment: Not as far as I have ever found in the Twitter API.  Sorry!